# Problems when my mac start

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

Just a little time, my mac has some problems when start. a prohibition logo appear and it's so slow until the system run... My mac run on yosemite 10.10.2

[image]

Comment: That is a indication of disk problem and Yosemite finding the boot sector. Try using the disk repair in the Utility folder.

Answer (score 1):

That is a indicator that the Yosemite has a problem with the "boot" sector on your disk. It could be your disk needs repair.

You can confirm that opening your Console (in the utility folder) and type "Disk" in the filter window. If you now see many Disk I/O than that is the problem.

You can try using the disk repair in the Disk utility in your Utility folder.

If that did not help, you should reinstall Yosemite using (holding) the cmd+r after restart.

If the problem is still there, you need a new disk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.... I used disk utility, the problem temporally disappeared but i have a new error in the image u can see 

This error maybe is the problem
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/hOuj9yx.png" title="source: imgur.com" /></a>

Comment: In English Warning: SUID file "System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/ARDAgent" has been modified and will not be repaired. is NOT a problem. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203172

Comment: You should use the "Repair Disk" in the bottom right corner, you used the "Repair Disk Permissions" that will not help you.

Comment: I used "repair disk"... But the problem not dissapear, sometimes the mac run with the circle signal another solution. 

Or, what happened if still use this disk ssd?